# Dual boot ubuntu 20.04 win10 legacy uefi

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Had a look at the related comments on this one although many similar, haven't come across one close enough

After a few unsuccessful attempts to install dual boot 20.04/win10, discovered the win10 bios is legacy

No option to install "alongside win10" as (two) previous experiences

Tried the "something else" option however got a bit lost with the rufus and partitioning options

Appears the basis of the problems may be the legacy (-v- UEFI) BIOS

Found the MBR2GPT.EXE tool to mod the bios from legacy to UEFI and the link reflects "applicable to win10 version 1703 Build 10.0.15063  AND LATER VERSIONS"

However a a bit farther down the page, the instructions reflect "(only) to win10 version 1703 Build 10.0.15063" and sent a request for clarification to the source  however  any experience with this, would appreciate the insight

https://www.wintips.org/how-to-change-legacy-to-uefi-without-reinstall-windows-10/

On a related matter, noticed a 25.09 gb unallocated partition on disk 0 & not sure what to do about that

Many thanks in advance

dbt1957

FOLLOW UP.....

Appreciate all the wisdom & please consider my apologies for my lack of experience ...

A couple points of clarification

(1) The legacy I am referring to is the legacy bios (as reflected in msinfo32 on this machine)  aka not  uefi

(2) As previously indicated, after two unsuccessful  attempts to dual-boot-"alongside" win10 based on the info collected so far, my best guess is  the legacy BIOS is not compatible with the dual-boot install/rufus set up as mentioned earlier

A full up ubuntu install over win10 without dual booting is an option, although the two previous adventures with dual booting win10/ubuntu were flawless and brief

Many thanks again

Comment: Somehow cut off the first line.....                                                                                                 Attempting to modify the legacy bios to UEFI on a Latitude E6520  i7 128 SSD iso dual booting ubuntu 20.04 with win10

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that Windows is installed as a legacy operating system? This is very uncommon, and would only exist that way if you installed it that way deliberately or upgraded from much older version.  How old is the Windows install? Was it originally Windows 7 or earlier? 25GB is the bare minimum requirement for Ubuntu so perhaps you should also free up a larger chunk of unpartitioned free space.

Comment: I would not have anything to do with the link you posted or the EXE you are talking about. This isn't necessary whether or not your Windows install is UEFI or BIOS. You just need to determine which you have and when you select the Ubuntu USB to boot use the same method. Booting volumes is a function of your motherboard hardware so if you aren't sure how to boot a USB as UEFI or BIOS then you need to review the documentation for your motherboard. Motherboards are all different

Comment: While you can convert MBR(msdos) to gpt, it really only works well with data only drives. Have seem multiple posts where users tried to convert a Windows install & ended up reinstalling. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned drives since 2012. If UEFI hardware best to have all installs in UEFI boot mode. Whatever you do be sure to have good backups of your data, not images as you cannot restore a BIOS boot image to a UEFI boot system.

Comment: When installing, the device will force the correct mode; "legacy" mode boots ubuntu into a purple screen...vs a black screen (uefi). I had a similar situation and problem with a dell device... after long hours I ended up figuring out the UEFI install, but that had a problem of not being able to power off or reboot Ubuntu (just hung)... so I resorted back to my original solution, which was to get one of my old machines that I KNEW was legacy, take the drives out, put my target dual boot drive in, and install ubuntu (from CD). once installed, worked fine back in its intended device.

Answer (score 0):

YUMI is a USB boot creator that can be used to make a bootable single boot or multi-system flash drive. [YUMI Legacy](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/YUMI-2.0.9.4.exe) (BIOS USB boot only) supports either NTFS or FAT32 format. You can use this version in Windows if your computer supports BIOS booting, and if you do not plan to run your Windows installers from YUMI in UEFI mode. Most modern motherboards still have Legacy BIOS firmware support though CMS Legacy mode.

YUMI can be used to format your selected USB drive, but be aware that all partitions on the selected disk will also be deleted. Ensure that you have made a backup of any information you want to keep before using YUMI on any drive. <sup>[source + YUMI Legacy download link](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)</sup>

[image]